# Convert an array of strings to an array of numbers in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, metabase

**How does one convert an array of string values into an array of numbers?**

**Background:**

Using Snowflake, I have a string input like "123, 45, 89" that I want to convert to an array of numbers (123, 45, 89) so that I can eventually compare against an int column like

```
WHERE id IN ( array of number here)
```

I think I can use `SPLIT('123, 45, 89', ',')` to get an array of strings, but get an error like this:

> SQL compilation error: Can not convert parameter 'SPLIT(?, ',')' of type [ARRAY] into expected type [NUMBER(38,0)]

For context, I am using Metabase, with a text filter as input to add those ids.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to leverage the `ARRAY_CONTAINS` function, instead of the `WHERE IN` option.  The tricky part is that the `SPLIT` function creates an array of strings, not numbers, so you'd have to convert the `id` field into a string, first.  You also need to be careful of spaces in your initial string, as that can create issues, as well.  However, something like this works:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE testing (id int);
  INSERT INTO testing (id) VALUES (45);
```

Then when querying this table with your string/array:

```
  SELECT t.id
  FROM testing t
  WHERE array_contains(t.id::varchar::variant,SPLIT('123,45,89',','));
```

Comment: But the question was "how to convert array of strings into array of ints".

Comment: But given the context of the problem that is being solved, this suits the need better.  The OP accepted the answer as what they were looking for, so I'm guessing that I interpreted the question correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Using [STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/strtok_split_to_table.html):

> Tokenizes a string with the given set of delimiters and **flattens the results into rows.**

```
SELECT * 
FROM t
WHERE id IN (SELECT s.value::INT 
             FROM TABLE(STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE('123,45,89',',')) s
             );
```

Or using the same pattern but as a JOIN:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM t
JOIN TABLE(STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE('123,45,89',',')) s ON t.id = s.value::INT;
```

---

How does it work:

Data prep:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t(id INT, col TEXT);
INSERT INTO t(id, col) VALUES (1, 'a'), (2,'b'), (45, 'c');
```

Subquery(at this point input could be treated as ordinary table):

```
SELECT s.value::INT FROM TABLE(STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE('123,45,89',',')) s;
-- 123
-- 45
-- 89
```